# Qt Message Box Won´t appear

Tags: qt, qmessagebox

i recently started working with qt and there occurs a problem i do not understand:

In this particular code i just want to show a Message Box, if a push button is clicked and a radio button is checked, but the Message Box wont appear. Can anyone help?

```
#include "thirddialog.h"
#include "ui_thirddialog.h"
#include <QMessageBox>



ThirdDialog::ThirdDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ThirdDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setWindowTitle("Eingabe UWZ");        /*Titelzeile*/
}

ThirdDialog::~ThirdDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}
void ThirdDialog::on_Back_clicked()
{
    close();
}

void ThirdDialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    if(ui->radioButton->isChecked())    {
        QMessageBox::information(this,"Title","1");

    }
    if(ui->radioButton_2->isChecked())  {
        QMessageBox::information(this,"Title","2");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me like you need to connect your on_pushButton_clicked() with the clicked() signal of the QPushButton.

```
connect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &ThirdDialog::on_pushButton_clicked);
```

For this to work on_pushButton_clicked() must be a slot:

```
class ThirdDialog {
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
    ...

    public slots:
        void on_pushButton_clicked();

    private:
    ...
};
```

Comment: you can read more about signal slots here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

Comment: with the connection it works,

thanks a lot ! :)